# Assigning Data to the users

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have one ms access 2007 database with frontend. users will access the front end and they will update some data. for making this process easy we have created one more frontend to upload the data to the database and those data will automatically come to the particular users front end.
here My problem is, eg: I will upload 100 claim numbers to the data base there are 5 users to work on this claims.
here I'm using the recordset to get the data from database and distributing to the users like FIFO. So until completing this users are not allowed to work on other process. so out 5 users normally 1 or 2 users will go for break until the remaining users completing the work. So  want to assign those 100 Claim to this 5 users equally.

```
Private sub Form_Load() 
Dim strqry as string  
Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset  
strQry="select xyz,abc,ffg from tblImport where isworked='N'"  
set rs = currentdb.openrecordset(strqry)

if not (rs.EOF and rs.BOF) then  
me.textbox0.value=Cstr(rs!xyz)  
me.textbox1.value=Cstr(rs!abc)  
end if

End sub
```

do we have any option is there to assign it equally?

Comment: Are you set on doing it this way? Because that is definitely not the way I would go about it. I would just add a "being processed" yes/no field and serve the records one at a time, allowing any number of users to work concurrently. That has the added advantage that it you have users working faster or claims that need less time to process you don't end up with users with nothing to do while others are still working. Unless for some business reason you do want each of your users to handle equal number of claims. Even then just add a per user counter and stop serving claims when reached.

Comment: You could add a "lockedForEdit' boolean field in your import table. Change your query to `SELECT TOP 20 ... from tblImport WHERE isWorked='N' and  lockedForEdit = 0`. Update all the records in the query so `lockedForEdit=True` before presenting in form for editing

Comment: Hi, guys. In this way users able to work but problem is this code i have pasted in form load so once the event occurs the first claim will come to their form fields and in my tblimport it will update as is assigned as "YES" and usworked as "N" , so some times some tricky users they will close that application from taskmanager and they will reopen it then he won't get that claim again. But i want to assigan that same again to them.

Comment: I'm thinking to create an alogoritham for this to update in that table itself to update their name itself. Like        No.of  Claims/no. Of assined users and it should update in that table. Anyone can help me on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code sample i have used to allocate/assign inventory to the users. This will assign inventory by priory wise to users.

```
strqry = "Select [ClaimID] from ClaimsTable"
strqry2 = "Select [UserName] from UsersTable"

rs1.Open strqry2, cn1, adOpenStatic
rs2.Open strqry, cn2, adOpenStatic

rs2.MoveFirst
Do While Not rs2.EOF

    If rs1.EOF = True Then rs1.MoveFirst

    claim = CStr(rs2![ClaimID])
    User = CStr(rs1![UserName])

    'Insert this data to any table and pull inventory for the users.   
    Debug.Print claim & "-" & User

    rs2.MoveNext
    rs1.MoveNext
Loop
```